# ActionCable Channel example 1: User appearances. Loop?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm currently trying to understand ActionCable to the fullest. Can someone explain me what exactly happens in this example code from official [doc](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable):

```
# app/channels/appearance_channel.rb
class AppearanceChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    current_user.appear
  end

  def unsubscribed
    current_user.disappear
  end

  def appear(data)
    current_user.appear on: data['appearing_on']
  end

  def away
    current_user.away
  end
end
```

In conjunction with:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/appearance.coffee
App.cable.subscriptions.create "AppearanceChannel",
  # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  connected: ->
    @install()
    @appear()

  # Called when the WebSocket connection is closed
  disconnected: ->
    @uninstall()

  # Called when the subscription is rejected by the server
  rejected: ->
    @uninstall()

  appear: ->
    # Calls `AppearanceChannel#appear(data)` on the server
    @perform("appear", appearing_on: $("main").data("appearing-on"))

  away: ->
    # Calls `AppearanceChannel#away` on the server
    @perform("away")


  buttonSelector = "[data-behavior~=appear_away]"

  install: ->
    $(document).on "turbolinks:load.appearance", =>
      @appear()

    $(document).on "click.appearance", buttonSelector, =>
      @away()
      false

    $(buttonSelector).show()

  uninstall: ->
    $(document).off(".appearance")
    $(buttonSelector).hide()
```

What I'm not sure about is, if current_user.appear creates a loop and therefore tells me that the user is logged in by pinging from client to server and back? And what does the 'on:' hashtag in the serverside appear function do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in the sense that it will be a loop from client -> server -> client.

In more detail, when connecting to the channel, the `@appear` function is called. We can see in that function, it uses `@perform` which invokes the server side function called `appear`. After this it's unfortunately quite vague, but let's say we want to broadcast back to all users that this person is now online.

An example of what could happen is that the `appear` function on the `User` model sets a boolean on the user object to indicate that they are online, and uses the `on` argument as follows:

```
# models/user.rb
def appear(data)
  self.update(online: true, current_room: data['on'])
end
```

After this, we would need a way to let other users know that this person is now online. So first we would have to broadcast this, and this could happen possibly after the update (there are better places to put it but for the purpose of explaining the data flow this will suffice):

```
# models/user.rb
def appear(data)
  self.update(online: true, current_room: data['on'])
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "AppearanceChannel", {event: 'appear', user_id: self.id, room: self.current_room}
end
```

So now all users connected to the Appearance Channel will receive the data, so we can add this to the front end. Let's say we just want to grab some sort of div that has the user information, and if they are online give them an class `online`, otherwise remove the class:

```
received: (data) ->
  userId = data.user_id
  eventType = data.event
  if eventType == 'appear'
    $('#user_' + userId).addClass 'online'
  else
    $('#user_' + userId).removeClass 'online'
```

So now it will update for all users connected to the channel, telling them that this user is now online.

Notice we are not using the room the user is currently in, but if we want we could grab it with `data.room`, and use it however we want.

Hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: Ty! Cleared things up for me. I misunderstood the current_user.appear function in subscribed.